# Debug View Hierarchy not showing for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller

I created and presented a UIImagePickerController and wanted to see what it constitutes. Instead I got this:

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

Why is debug View Hierarchy not showing for UIImagePickerController and all its views and instead it only shows one black view? Can I technically make the same for my own views and view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is RemoteView[1]. iOS has another project to display the ViewController and stream it to your app. The remote process draws into the context of the current app using CALayerHost[2]. PoC example (not using XPC though)[3]

[1] https://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/.
[2] http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CALayerHost.
[3] https://github.com/freerunnering/libremoteview